# Add text on every nth line

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file `logs.txt`. I would like to insert into the file the text `finished`
on every fourth line. Is it possible with `sed` or other tool?

The resulting file would look like this.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
finish
ddd
eee
fff
finish
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process two more lines, then add the "finish":

```
sed -e 'n; n; a finish'
```

Or, with GNU sed, you can use an address that means "start on line 3, repeat every 3rd line":

```
sed -e '3~3 a finish'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` it is pretty simple:

```
awk '1; NR%3 == 0 { print "finish" }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Or we could do it by reverse approach done by @anubhava sir too here by printing text in fourth line and then printing actual line content.

```
awk -v line="4" '
FNR%line==0{
  print "finish"
}
1;
' Input_file
```